# I need to connect to my exchange sever via smtp on my PC like I do on my phone

Tags: exchange, smtp

On my phone (Android 4.1) I can add an exchange account with the following info all under "Incoming Settings":

```
-email address [me@ourcompany.co.uk]
-password
-domain\username [serversdomain\myusername]
-server url [smtp.ourcompany.co.uk]
-Port [443]
```

This works great, allows access to the calendar and contact as well as mail. I can connect outlook to the server when i am on the same network, or connected to it via a VPN. But, if i am on a different network it will not connect.

I have tried several different email clients (thunderbird, emMail, evolution) and all require additional settings, some that i cannot provide:

```
-Name [Ben]
-email address [me@ourcompany.co.uk]
-password
-Incoming Server Type [IMAP or POP3]
-Incoming Server hostname [smtp.ourcompany.co.uk] ??? not sure about this
-Incoming Server port [443] 
-Incoming SSL [SSL/TLS]
-Incoming Authentication [Normal Password]
-Outgoing Server Type [SMTP]
-Outgoing Server hostname [smtp.ourcompany.co.uk]
-Outgoing Server port [25] 
-Outgoing SSL [SSL/TLS]
-Outgoing Authentication [Normal Password]
```

This will connect quite happily to the smtp server for outgoing mail, but will not connect to the server for incoming mail.

My questions are, can someone:
    -tell me where i am going wrong? 
    -Tell me why my phone can connect with less settings than PC mail clients?
    -point me to a PC client that will work with the same settings as my phone?

Cheers